# java - newline detection in strings

Tags: java, string, newline

I know that similar questions have been asked several times, but the answers I saw are either workarounds or simply incorrect.

The basic problem is fairly simple: A method gives me a string read from a file and I need to check if this string contains newline.

Now to the tricky part: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) currently lists eight types of characters or character combinations which may, dependent on the system, denote a newline. So checking for the common `\n` and `\r`, an answer, that I often read, is not the way to go. Walking through the string and compare its characters with `System.getProperty("line.separator")` might also fail, since a possible newline representation is `\r\n', that will trigger this comparison twice, though its only one newline.

However, this has to be possible. What option am I missing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this, "that will trigger this comparison twice". Why would it happen twice? But are the files you are reading, generated/created on the same machine/os that you are running this application?

Comment: I mean, if I check for `\r` as trigger and for `\n` as trigger and I'm on an os which gives me `\r\n` for a newline, a char-by-char comparison will find two newlines, however there has been only one.

Also, the files may come from different systems with different os and the application has to run on different systems with different os.

Comment: But wouldn't you be looking for the occurrence of `\r\n` as a whole, not both `\r` and `\n`. For instance `StringUtils.countMatches("ab\r\ncd\r\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"))` on a machine that has `\r\n` as the line separator would return 2. If you don't know the OS the file originated from, I'd say go with Braj's method.

Comment: If I look for the occurence of `\r\n` as a whole, I don't find newline on systems that use either only `\r` or only `\n`. So I will need a loop that checks first, if `\r\n` appears, and then, if it does not appear, if any other single-char newline indicator appears. This will result in the necessity to run through the string twice in most cases, what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the regex pattern `^(.*)$` together with the modifier `Pattern.MULTILINE`. A method that checks if a string contains any new line character would look like this:

```
static boolean containsNewLine(String str) {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    return regex.split(str).length > 0;
}
```

It splits the string in n parts, depending on the number of newline characters. If the string contains any newline character, the `length` will be greater than 0.

Normally `^` and `$`  will match only the beginning and the end of the string, but you can change this behavior by passing `Pattern.MULTILINE`. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> In multiline mode the expressions ^ and $ match just after or just before, respectively, a line terminator or the end of the input sequence. By default these expressions only match at the beginning and the end of the entire input sequence.

Comment: Sorry for being late, I haven't had the time to implement anything during the last weeks. However, this solution works great, if I use only "^" as pattern instead of "^(.*)$", which does not work at all. Since this is also completely platform independent, it's definitely the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Regex pattern `\r?\n` where `\r` is optional.

sample code:

```
    String str = "abc\r\nlmn\nxyz";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\r?\n");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    int count=0;
    while(matcher.find()){
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);    // prints 2
```

Comment: This handles only two out of eight possible newline indicators. It finds `CR+LF` and a single `LF`, but it wont find a single `CR`, `VT`, `FF`, `NEL`, `LS`, or `PS`.